# How do you have a program close when another one is closed?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make it so that when I open a batch file, it will open 2 programs, and when the program `Osu!` closes, it will also close the program `TabletDriverGUI` The programs open, but I don't know how to close it.

Code:

```
start /d "C:\Users\ninja\AppData\Local\osu!" osu!.exe

start /min "TabletDriverGUI" "D:\EXE Files\Drivers\TabletDriverV0.2.3\TabletDriverV0.2.3\TabletDriverGUI.exe"

tasklist /V /FI "Osu! eq osu.exe*"
tasklist /V /FI "TabletDriverGUI eq TabletDriverGUI.exe*"

:loop
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
goto loop
) else (
taskkill /FI "TabletDriverGUI eq TabletDriverGUI.exe*"
)
```

Comment: You are mistaken on the usage of the /FI option. The help file is pretty clear on how to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553727/batch-taskkill-timeout-without-waiting-for-timer?rq=1

Comment: Your loop is useless as you are just checking `%ErrorLevel%` which will not change; `:loop` must be placed before the command that is supposed to set that value...